# large language model for incident solving

Tags: llm

we want to run a llm locally in our company and we want to give it the code, the documantation and the incidents so it can help to solve the incidents.

We think about alpaca or llama for this task. Which llm would be the best and how to implement/use it for this task?

Comment: By "incident solving", do you mean modifying the code to solve bugs?

Comment: Yes that would be the best way to help with the incidents.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul do you have any lmm in mind that could be good for this use case?

Comment: That sounds like a hard problem for a current LLM to solve, especially if you have more than a handful of source code files.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul is it totally impossible or is there a LLM that could help? Which is the best LLM for coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. I have had a few conversations recently where a similar topic has come up, around automating L2/L3 using incident resolution agents. The below summary is how I would approach it:

Here is a way to approach this problem:

a) Engine: This is in essence any LLM. You can deploy it locally if you want, you could also use something out of the box (like Azure OpenAI which gives you the security). I'd base this on an aprpoximate ticket count. If you think you need scale, then go with a hyper-scalar. Your LLM should have access to your code base (either embedding, or via direct access as a prompt), as well as access to your documents (embeddings).

b) Processing: When a ticket is raised, run 2-3 prompts, one to fetch relevant information from your documentation on potential solutions, another to check if there are other tickets that have been solved in a similar way. Then based on this, find the code where the issue exists, and then ask the LLM to rewrite the function to fix the issue. This is where I would be very careful and commit the code after a human can test it :)

c) Outcome: if its a positive outcome, I would then use the ticket, the data analysed and the code changed (old vs new code) to write a new document and store it back into the repository.

This is one way to approach this challenge.

Finally, if you want to run it locally and you are happy to spend time 'configuring and maintaining' the models, go with LLama. If you want to use something out of the box, go with Azure OpenAI.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Thsnk you very much!